# Problema trayendo datos de Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

saludes amigos tengo un inconveniente con vuex .. el objetivo es cargar y pintar los datos de unas empresas que vienen por un API 
y al dar click que me vaya a otra pagina y se pueda editar la informacion en un formulario todo construido en vuex tambien.
- La parte de cargar y pintar los datos no hay problema (1). lo realize creando un store y almacenando los datos en este luego llamo a una computed property y lo pinto(2)(3)(4)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Al hacer click cargo el array perfilEmpresa q esta en el store pasandole el index obtenido en el vfor(5)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- El problema radica en q deseo accesar al store para bajar esos datos del array perfilEmpresa y cargar en el formulario para ser editados pero no me muestra
nada, acalro que esto esta en otro archivo.
- El codigo de la pagina del formulario es este(6)(7) y este es el resultado del console.log donde me muestra q no hay nada en el store.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
NOTA: trabajo sobre una plantilla Admillte. 
De antemano agradezco la informacion

Answer (score 0):

Saludes Solucione mi inconveniente usado la siguiente libreria:
[Vuex persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist)

No es buena practica para SPA ya que con vuex la misma arquitectura te permite utilizar el mismo store para todos los componentes.